# Understanding how to output multiclass segmentation using UNet in Pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network, unet-neural-network

So I have been learning about UNets and I managed to get the binary classification UNet model to work using some [github examples](https://github.com/nikhilroxtomar/Retina-Blood-Vessel-Segmentation-in-PyTorch). However, I am now trying to figure out how this translates to multiclass segmentation problems. In the binary case, my input image was 512x512 with 3 channels for RGB, the masks were 512x512x1 and the output of the UNet was a 512x512 image with 1 channel representing the binary segmentation.
But with a multiclass problem, my masks are still 512x512 images but now have 3 channels for RGB where different objects in the mask are labeled with 5 different solid colors. So in total, the mask image is showing that there are 5 classes. Do we now take this RGB mask and export out the 5 individual colors to create 5 channels where each channel represents a class. This way the mask is going to be size 512x512x5 and the input image is still 512x512x3?

In this case, I had changed the output channels from 1 to a 5 in my final UNet layer so it becomes  `self.outputs = nn.Conv2d(64, 5, kernel_size=1, padding=0)`.  And then I was thinking of just using the  following loss function and keeping everything from the binary case the same:

```
class DiceBCELoss(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, weight=None, size_average=True):
        super(DiceBCELoss, self).__init__()

    def forward(self, inputs, targets, smooth=1):

        #comment out if your model contains a sigmoid or equivalent activation layer
        inputs = torch.sigmoid(inputs)

        #flatten label and prediction tensors
        inputs = inputs.view(-1)
        targets = targets.view(-1)

        intersection = (inputs * targets).sum()
        dice_loss = 1 - (2.*intersection + smooth)/(inputs.sum() + targets.sum() + smooth)
        BCE = F.binary_cross_entropy(inputs, targets, reduction='mean')
        Dice_BCE = BCE + dice_loss

        return Dice_BCE
```

The other alternative I was thinking was to convert the 512x512x3 mask to grayscale where there are now 5 different shades representing the 5 classes. I then look at the output of the UNet and for each pixel, I compare its value with the value of the corresponding mask pixel using the above loss function.

Answer (score 1):

> This way the mask is going to be size 512x512x5 and the input image is still 512x512x3?

Yes that would be a standard way of doing it, if you want to save values for each output class (e.g., a probability for each class).

> The other alternative I was thinking was to convert the 512x512x3 mask to grayscale where there are now 5 different shades representing the 5 classes. I then look at the output of the UNet and for each pixel, I compare its value with the value of the corresponding mask pixel using the above loss function.

This would only work with one-hot encoding of the output. In other words, if your output is that one class is true, and all others are false, then your output could be of shape 512 x 512 x 1 and the class could be encoded by an integer value (ranging from 0 to 4).

So which setup to use mostly depends on your use-case/activation function. Do you want to output 1 value per class, or just one class? If you would still use `cross_entropy` as loss function, that would give you the former (but could be converted to 1 class by an argmax for example). Note that you can't use *binary* cross entropy for multi-class targets, but use regular cross entropy instead: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss.html